# Block IPs if they access a resource

Tags: apache-2.2, iptables, block, attacks

I own a server that it's costantly being attacked by scripts (that try to access to phpMyAdmin's setup file's and stuff like this). I've heard that many people get this kinds of attacks, but I'm starting to worry since they are getting more common (last month I got 2 attacks, and on november 7th there are 3 attempts already (1st, 4th and 6th of nov).

I'm not really concerned about it, since I don't have any database. All the info i have on that server is absolutely public, but I'm worried about that attacking-rate increase.

So I thought I could -temporarily- block the IPs that come from those attackers, or something that could make my server ignore requests that ask for phpMyAdmin, pma, xamp, etc.

Is there something like that? my server is Linux+Apache+Php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a program called [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which is designed to watch a log file for text matching a regexp - usually signatures of a failed login, or script attack - and block the requesting IP for a configurable period of time via `iptables` rules.

Given that their main page explicitly mentions watching an apache logfile, then provided you can say exactly what the log signature of one of these "attacks" looks like, I suspect this might be just the sort of thing you're looking for.

Comment: Exactly, I was looking for something like that, and I think this will work. Thank you very much